# K&R Exercise 6-1 In some cases getword function can't read EOF

Tags: c, eof

I just finished exercise 6.1 in the book ***The C Programming Language***, ***Second Edition*** (by ***K&R***), here is the exercise problem:

> Our version of getword does not properly handle underscores, string constants,
>   comments, or preprocessor control lines. Write a better version.

Here is the getword function in the book:

```
    int getword(char *word, int lim)
    {
        int c;
        char *w = word;
        while (isspace(c = getch()))
            ;
        if (c != EOF)
            *w++ = c;
        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            *w = '\0';
            return c;
        }
        for ( ; --lim > 0; w++)
            if (!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
                ungetch(*w);
                break;
            }
        *w = '\0';
        return word[0];
    }
```

Function calling in the main():

```
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF) {...}
```

Here is my getword function:

```
int getword(char *word, int lim)
{
    int c, c1;
    char *w = word;
    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    else    
        return EOF;
   // handle comments: /* */ 
    if ( c == '/') {
        if ((c1 = getch()) == '*') {
            keytab[31].count++;
            int ok = 1;
            while (ok) {
                // skip characters in comment lines
                while ((c = getch()) != EOF || c != '*')
                    ;
                if (c == EOF)
                    return EOF;
                if ((c = getch()) == '/')
                    ok = 0;
            }
            return COMMENT;
        }
         // handle comments : //
        else if (c1 == '/') {
            keytab[32].count++;
            while ((c = getch()) != EOF || c != '\n')
                ;
            if (c == EOF)
                return EOF;
            return COMMENT;
        }
        else
            return c;
    }
    // handle preprocessor control lines, start with '#'
    if (c == '#') {
        keytab[34].count++;
        while ((c = getch()) != EOF || c != '\n')
            ;
        if (c == EOF)
            return EOF;
        return '#';
    }
    // handle string constants, " "
    else if (c == '\"') {
        while ((c1 = getch()) != EOF || c1 != '\"')
            ;
        if (c1 == EOF)
            return EOF;
        keytab[33].count++;
        return CONSTANT;
    }
    else if (c != '_' && !isalpha(c)) {
        while ((c = getch()) != EOF && !isspace(c))
            ;
        if (c == EOF)
            return EOF;
        return NOT;
    }
    // c is '_' or letter , scan characters until EOF or space, or punctuation
    // to get a complete word
    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++)
        if ((*w = getch()) == EOF || isspace(*w) || ispunct(*w)) {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    *w = '\0';
    return WORD;
}
```

If I don't enter **"**,  **//**  ,  **/*** or **#**, the code will run normally and I can stop input by enterint ctrl + d. But once I enter one of the above characters, the program can't read EOF, thus I can't stop the input. I debug the program by gdb but still don't get it. So what happens?

Comment: Note that `/* */` comment handler is amiss.  Consider `"/* **/"` fails to exit comment.  Research `unget()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` versus `||`

```
while ((c = getch()) != EOF || c != '*')
```

Above is always true.

Perhaps

```
while ((c = getch()) != EOF && c != '*')
```